# Dynamic locale on angular2/moment and ngx-translate

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular2-moment

> Angular 4.x - ngx-translate - angular2-moment

How to use "amTimeAgo" and "amLocale" with dynamic locale? I mean, 
i.e this works

```
<p> {{ note.createdAt | amLocale: 'es' | amTimeAgo  }} </p>
```

but I want to convert 'es' into a dynamic variable. 
What is the best approach? Using a Custom Pipe with ngx-translate service or... call from inside the component like this:

```
//myComponent.ts
ngOnInit() {
        this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
            this.momentLang = event.lang;
        });
    }

// myComponent.html
<p> {{ note.createdAt | amLocale: momentLang  | amTimeAgo  }} </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your interceptor component

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

const language = localStorage.getItem('language'); (language setted before)
moment.locale(language);
```